# Page reload causes 404 not found using nginx auth_basic + react app

Tags: nginx, react-router

So I am trying to secure a **staging** server using nginx basic auth module using the following:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name <something>;

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<something>/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<something>/privkey.pem;

    gzip_static   on;
    brotli_static on;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
        auth_basic "Restricted Access";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/passwords/htpasswd;
    }

    # only enable on non-production environments
    location /robots.txt {return 200 "User-agent: *\nDisallow: / \nNoindex: / \n";}
}
```

While it works, due to the app nature - this is a single page application, if I reload the page (e.g /dashboard) I get `404 not found`.

It only works on `/` but this is how it is supposed to work for a single-page app. Any clues welcome

PS: Happy new year if 2020 has reached you.

Comment: Not sure if this will fix your specific problem, but the final term of the `try_files` statement should have a leading `/`. i.e. `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;`

Comment: @RichardSmith hey actually this seems to fix the issue!